# beautify dataframe to html table sent by email

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I have periodic job sending me email every day with data i am collecting in one py script.

```
print('\n'+"Total daily events for "+str(yesterday) +": {:,}".format(total_events)+'\n')
query = """
select account_id, count(*)
from "public"."bus_request" where date = '2020-06-23' 
group by account_id


"""
df_total_events = load_data_from_redshift(query)
```

load_data_from_redshift return me datafram. How do i have in one email the first print and the data frame df_total_events as good table to be viewed? i tried tabulate but is not so much good visual to show managers. any good ideas?